# Convert date over to PostgreSQL using Date_trunc

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, type-conversion

I have a date I am wanting to convert and I can't seem to switch it over to PostgreSQL format, I would like to use date_trunc if possible.

```
 convert(VARCHAR(25), dateadd('dd', -('day'(dte.calendar_date) - 1), dte.CalendarDate), 101)
```

Comment: Please post an example of input data and expected output data.

Comment: What does this expression do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first date of the month, then use:

```
 date_trunc('month', dte.CalendarDate)
```

Your logic looks vaguely like you are trying to subtract the day number of the month, which is why I think this is what you are want to do.